# Remote Access to localhost website - IIS Express

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, windows-8.1, remote-access, iis-express

I'm trying to put a VisualStudio2012 ASP.NET MVC 4 website accessible from another computer, in the same subnet.
I already opened my applicationhost.config file, in the IIS Express folder, and added to my binding another row with my IP:

```
  <site name="MedicalTransactions_Security" id="2">
            <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Users\aa\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\MedicalTransactions_Security\MedicalTransactions_Security" />
            </application>
            <bindings>
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:50514:localhost" />
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:50514:10.250.38.242" />
            </bindings>
   </site>
```

I'm using Windows 8.1, so then I opened my administrative prompt and added:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://10.250.38.242:50514/ user=everyone
```

Then, added:

> netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="IISExpressWeb" dir=in protocol=tcp localport=50514 profile=private remoteip=localsubnet action=allow
>   so that my firewall allows remote access from that specific port.

When I try to access: 10.250.38.242:50514 from another computer, in the same network it doesn't work.. It says that the server where the page is located, isn't responding..

I don't know what should I do more to make it work..
Can you help?

Thank you,
Best Regards,
William.

Comment: did you find any answer to this, it did work for me, but suddenly stopped working and i have no clue what has happend, if its an update or what.

Comment: No, I didn't.. I'm still waiting for an answer..

Comment: Found the answer, was an external application that recently did activate its firewall and then it didnt work, just removed that firewall and it started to work again.